# ODBC error 10054 when trying to connect from Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, odbc, pyodbc

I wanted to convert some of my Python scripts to Docker containers. Inside of my Python script, I am using pyodbc to make SQL Server selects and inserts. I found an example of how to do this online and it is not functioning how I would expect.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

# download appropriate package for the OS version
# Debian 11
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list  \
    > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN exit
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18

# upgrade pip and install requirements.
COPY /requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD [ "python", "myapp.py" ]
```

myapp.py

```
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

The error I get is this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try appending `;Encrypt=no` to the end of your connection string?

Comment: This did not work @GordThompson

Comment: You might get some more ideas here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/610

Comment: Sometimes `;Encrypt=false` works where `;Encrypt=no` does not. Refer to [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) as to why this could even be required.

Comment: `TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746` suggests that you're connecting to a very old version of SQL Server, or one that hasn't had service packs and/or cumulative updates applied, and it does not support TLS 1.2 connections, ref: [KB3135244 - TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe). Modern ODBC drivers require encrypted connections to support TLS 1.2 or later. If you connect to your SQL Server via another tool, such as SSMS, what does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?